# Paste a vector of vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of vectors e.g.

```
c(c('a','b'), c('a','b'))
```

I want to join the sub-vectors with `paste` e.g.

```
lapply(c(c('a','b'), c('a','b')), paste)
```

which that results in

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "a"

[[4]]
[1] "b"
```

however I want the result to be

```
[[1]]
[1] "a b"

[[2]]
[1] "a b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of vectors. And in the `paste` function, you want to `collapse` the elements, so you can do:

```
lapply(list(c('a','b'), c('a','b')), paste, collapse = " ")

[[1]]
[1] "a b"

[[2]]
[1] "a b"
```